# Adding a new row to empty dataframe located in data lake

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, pyspark

I created a empty dataframe table to location at Delta by using this code below:

```
deltaResultPath = "/ml/streaming-analysis/delta/Result"

# Create Delta Lake table
sqlq = "CREATE TABLE stockDailyPrices_delta USING DELTA LOCATION '" + deltaResultPath + "'"
spark.sql(sqlq)
```

I am new to spark and do not fully understand sparkSQL code.  What I want to do is instead of inserting values from another dataframe, I would like to add values generated in python script. 
Something like modifying the code from:

```
insert_sql = "insert into stockDailyPrices_delta select f.* from stockDailyPrices f where f.price_date >= '"  + price_date_min.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "' and f.price_date <= '" + price_date_max.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "'"
spark.sql(insert_sql)
```

to

```
Time = 10
cpu_temp = 3
dsp_temp = 5
insert_sql = "insert into df (Time, cpu_temp, dsp_temp) values (%s, %s, %s)"
spark.sql(insert_sql)
```

However, I see the error following:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 

ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'Time' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'DESC', 'VALUES', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DESCRIBE', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'UPDATE', 'REDUCE'}(line 1, pos 16)\n\n== SQL ==\ninsert into df (Time, cpu_temp, dsp_temp) values (%s, %s, %s)\n----------------^^^\n"
```

How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work with something like this

```
spark.sql("insert into Result_delta select {} as Time, {} as cpu_temp, {} as dsp_temp".format(Time, cpu_temp, dsp_temp))
```